# Android Notifications Techniques

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am developing an server based Android app in which i have to notify user. Please suggest me some techniques to do this. How do Whatsapp, Facebook notifies the user?

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion , you need

1. Server to run web application
2. web application to register and send notifications to devices where your app installed.
3. client / server keys registered with Google Cloud Messaging API

to perform this

Comment: not sure why you reject GCM, but there are several alternatives , read here https://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/learnmore                              Here is a good anwser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291527/alternative-to-building-push-notification-system-from-scratch

Comment: thanks...
content helped me a lot...
actually the main reason for not Using GCM is my client wants that every user may not have a Google Account
so how that user can get notification...